# Configure Grunt-Bower-Install path for a Component

Tags: gruntjs, bower

How do I specify the default file to use for a bower component so that it will be injected properly by [grunt-bower-install](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install)?

I am working with [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) and they have different files depending on your localization. The file I'm wanting to include is not in the root of bower_components/datejs directory so I get the error:

> datejs was not injected in your file.
>
> Please go take a look in
> "app/bower_components/datejs" for the file you need, then manually
> include it in your file.

I'm trying my hardest to avoid hardcoding datejs into my index file and don't really want to move "date-en-US.js" file into the root of the datejs directory either.

This is the structure of the datejs bower component.

```
bower_components
└── datejs
    └── build
        └── ...
        └── date-en-US.js
        └── ...
    └── src
    └── test
```

And just in case this helps, this is the .bower.json file that is located in the datejs bower component path:

```
{
  "name": "datejs",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/datejs/Datejs",
  "_release": "7bdddb55d6",
  "_resolution": {
    "type": "branch",
    "branch": "master",
    "commit": "7bdddb55d69719e42c358c3a2b7df706ff3090f8"
  },
  "_source": "git://github.com/datejs/Datejs.git",
  "_target": "*",
  "_originalSource": "datejs",
  "_direct": true
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little late to the party but you can override the main property of a repo to define whatever file you want to inject into your app. To do this you need to use the `overrides` property in **YOUR** `bower.json`.

Try this:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "dependencies": {
    "datejs": "x.x.x"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "datejs": {
      "main": "build/date-en-US.js"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed! And more explanations about it from [wiredep](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides), from [grunt-wiredep](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep#behind-the-scenes). Thx @nknj

Answer (score 3):

I too was frustrated by this a few times. What I found in my cases was that "grunt bower-install" requires a "main" entry in the .bower.json. It's a string or array of strings that point to the relevant JS and/or CSS files that should be installed.

In your case I do not see the "main" and would suggest you create one that contains the desired datejs files. I would suggest the source files if you intend to use grunt for minification/etc. You can look at other successful components to see examples of the "main" entry.

I suspect that some components do not supply the entry because they have no single usage pattern (i.e. you can mix and match the files you require), but this is just speculation on my part.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it was that. However, what happens if I were to update my bower components in the future? Wouldn't that change in the .bower.json file be overwritten?

Comment: Shamefully I admit that I may be more of a noob then you envision. If a more qualified expert sees this and comments, I will update my response. I haven't tested the update use case yet. To protect myself I forced the .bower.json files into my source control, which will at least make visible any updates. In one case I opened a github issue with the dev since I thought they could change it themselves. However, the use case where "main" could be one of many files or file combinations seems unserved by Bower. I am not sufficiently competent to make this complaint, however.

Comment: @corporatedrone, answered this question as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this in your grunt file:

```
'bower-install': {
     fileTypes: {
         fileExtension: {
             detect: {
                 typeOfBowerFile: /-en-US.js/
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I didn't try this out, and my regex might be off.  But accoriding to the [grunt-bower-install readme](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install), it states `See [wiredep's](https://github.com/stephenplusplus/wiredep) readme for more options of customization` and there it shows using the above configuration.

Essentially - `grunt-bower-install` doesn't know what to look for. This option appears to tell it that info.